# How can i regenerate django request from unittest?

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-unittest, django-request

**Request**

```
GET /operation/data_resample_ranges/?activeElements=%7B%22resample_ranges%22:%7B%22(5)(0)Signal_1%5B%20%5D%22:%22mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0
-0%22,%22(5)(0)Signal_2%5B%20%5D%22:%22mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0-1%22,%22(5)(0)Signal_3%5B%20%5D%22:%22mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0-2%22%7D%7D
```

**Decoded**

```
GET /operation/data_resample_ranges/?activeElements={"resample_ranges":{"(5)(0)Signal_1[ ]":"mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0
-0","(5)(0)Signal_2[ ]":"mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0-1","(5)(0)Signal_3[ ]":"mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0-2"}}
```

I am writing a test using unittest but i am not getting the exact request like above shown in request.

My test is given below:

```
    def test_get_saved_model_data(self):

    activeElements = {
        "resample_ranges": {"(5)(0)Signal_1[ ]": "mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0- 0",
                            "(5)(0)Signal_2[]":"mongodb~test_db~5 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 1",
                            "(5)(0)Signal_3[]":"mongodb~test_db~5 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 2"
                            }
    }

    response = requests.get(OPERATION_API_URL, json.dumps(activeElements))
```

How can i get the exact request?

Answer (score 1):

As I solved it, so wanted to write it here. May be it will be helpful for someone else later.

```
def test_get_saved_model_data(self):

    data = { 
        "activeElements" :json.dump( {
        "resample_ranges": {"(5)(0)Signal_1[ ]": "mongodb~test_db~5-0-0-0-0- 0",
                            "(5)(0)Signal_2[]":"mongodb~test_db~5 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 1",
                            "(5)(0)Signal_3[]":"mongodb~test_db~5 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 2"
                            }
    })
    }

    response = requests.get(OPERATION_API_URL, params=data)
```